# Vc++ Tree View Control

Tags: visual-c++

[image]I've created an MFC Application using tree control which shows all directories and folders in my system. Now I want to give  image left to the  to drives and folder . The Current Output is given.

Comment: Can you provide some details........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this type of structure thec you can go to this [link](http://www.functionx.com/visualc/treeview/tvdlg1.htm)

[image]

**Edit**

If you want to populate Directory structure in tree view then can use [DirectoryInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s2fzb02%28v=vs.90%29)

Comment: It's cool, But I Want C,D & E as Drives and folders as folder images.( How it appears in our system)